# Android Adding watermark using FFMPEG after reading from resources

Tags: android, ffmpeg, watermark

I need little help about adding watermark after reading it from the app reasources.. I have done this and worked quite awesome when I read directly from a specific folder. but now I want to make the idea generic and want to read it from resources then apply on video. 
I am trying this to read watermark from drawable

```
Uri waterMark = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.app.videoedit/"+R.drawable.watermark);
```

My command is here

```
complexCommand =new String[] {"ffmpeg","-y" ,"-i", externalPath,"-i", outputAudioFile, "-strict","experimental",
"-filter_complex",
"[1:a]atempo=1.0[a1];" +
"movie="
+waterMark /////////////////////// here is that path 
+" [watermark];" +
"[0:v][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w-10):(main_h-overlay_h-10)    [outv]",
"-map", "[outv]", "-map", "[a1]",
 "-s", "480x320","-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4","-ab",    "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050",
"-shortest",PATH+"merged.mp4"};
```

Comment: It is been a while when this question is posted but did you find solution for this? I'm facing with same problem. Providing watermark path to the `FFmpeg`

Comment: Hey, I have moved on, I really don't remember. 3 years have been past.